# Balancing a set of weights

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics

Let $w:=(w_1,\dots,w_n)$ be an $n$-tuple of natural numbers, which may be thought of as weights. Let us say that $w$ is good if there is a set $J\subseteq[n]:=\{1,\dots,n\}$ such that
$$\sum_{j\in J}w_j=\sum_{j\in[n]\setminus J}w_j.$$
The goodness condition may be thought of as balancing the weights.

The problem is to find a nontrivial, non-tautological (ideally necessary and sufficient) condition for a given $w$ to be good.

Some necessary conditions for the goodness of $w$ are obvious. In particular, $\sum_{j\in[n]}w_j$ must be even. It is also clear that the largest of the $w_j$'s cannot be greater than the sum of the other $w_j$'s; e.g., $w=(2,4,4,12)$ is not good because $12=\max(2,4,4,12)>2+4+4$. Also, $w$ will not be good if, say, the largest of the $w_j$'s is less than the sum of the other $w_j$'s while the sum of the largest and the smallest of the $w_j$'s is greater than the sum of the other $w_j$'s; e.g., $w=(2,4,4,8)$ is not good because $8=\max(2,4,4,8)\ge\min(2,4,4,8)=2$, $8<2+4+4$, and $8+2>4+4$.

Comment: The problem of identifying ''good'' n-tuples is weakly NP-complete ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem ), so there are some limitations on the simplicity of equivalent conditions.

Comment: if $w_1\le w_2\le\ldots\le w_n$ and $w_i\le 1+w_1+\ldots+w_{i-1}$ for $i=1, \ldots, n$ then any positive integer between 1 and $w_1+\ldots+w_n$ is a symbol of certain subcollection of $w_i$'s. In particular, if additionally the sum is even, the necessary $J$ exists.

Comment: Thank you very much, Lorenzo Najt and Fedor Petrov, for your comments.